# Mostrar modal despues de refrescar la pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal

Buenas tardes tengo una función que refresca mi pantalla para hacer unas modificaciones visuales y me gustaría que después se abriera un modal mostrando una cierta información, pero mi problema es que abre el modal y después refresca la pagina a pesar que el orden en las llamadas es el contrario

```
   function pendientes(eje) {
    var Periodo = $('#select').val();
    url = "Principal_indicador.php";
    $(location).attr('href', url);
    muestraDetalle3(); //funcion del modal

}


function muestraDetalle3() {

    $(".h").css('background-color', "#4d4d57");
    $("#myModal3").modal({
        backdrop: false
    });
    $.post("Pedientes.php", {
       
    }, function(data) {
        $(".detalle").html('');
        $(".detalle").html(data);
    });
}
```

trate con la función setTimeout pero no me hacia nada, alomejor la puse mal, espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: mm ok y como seria de esa forma?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a hacerlo con [document-ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready)

Lo que puedes hacer es mandar una variable a tu página a la hora de refrescarla por el método GET que indique si tienes que mostrar el modal o no.